# jquery mobile autocomplete error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to implement Jquery Mobile Autocomplete (https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js).

The following code shows the Search Field and Target:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input id="stockItem_id" name="stockXferDetail.stockItem.title" type="text" value="" />
    <ul id="stockItemList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
</div>
```

The following code shows the script/s:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#stockItem_id").autocomplete({
             target: $("#stockItemList"),
             source: '/StockItem/AutoCompleteStockItem',
             minLength: 1
         });
    });
</script>
```

However, this solution generates the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'
```

I can fix the error by referencing the "jquery-ui" script.  However, the results of the autocomplete function are not shown in the Target and are displayed in raw html.

Also, the example at http://www.andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/complex.html does not use/require "jquery-ui".

Comment: any other error in the browser console

Comment: Yes "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Comment: which line is causing the error

Comment: has no method 'autocomplete' mostly means that the autocomplete plugin  was not correctly included in page..

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  52466/Scripts/jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2-min.js:4
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete' 2398:91
(anonymous function) 2398:91
fire jquery-1.8.2.js:974
self.fireWith jquery-1.8.2.js:1082
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.8.2.js:406
DOMContentLoaded jquery-1.8.2.js:83

Answer (score -1):

Problem resolved: when downloading the "jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2-min.js" file, I mistakenly downloaded the html download page.  Very embarrassing school-boy mistake :-(